# Rss to Pass Dynamic Parameter values used in SSRS parameters

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, vbscript, rss

Is it possible to use the dynamic parameter values in SSRS report in to the RSS script to produce the files automatically.

{"Option1, Option2, Option3"}  - These values change and every time a new option had to be manually added to this list.

`Dim varNames As String() = {"Option1, Option2, Option3"}
For each nameparam As String in varNames
  Dim parameters(0) As ParameterValue
  parameters(0) = New ParameterValue()
  parameters(0).Name = "Parameter"
  parameters(0).Value = nameparam`

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a data driven subscription for this (DDS). DDS requires SQL Server Enterprise (or Developer) edition to use. If you don't have that you can try to hack something together in the database (search Google for data driven subscriptions without enterprise edition) but all of the options (except for rolling your own custom application do it) have some sort of fall back.

The DDS is effectively a query in the database. For each row returned from that query, 1 file/email/report will be delivered. The columns in the data driven query can bind back to report parameters, filename, email subject, etc.

### OLD ANSWER BEFORE CLARIFICATION IN THE COMMENTS

Can you use another dataset which runs a query to obtain the values you wish your parameter to include? The dataset would return a 2 column table (a `Label` and `Value`). And then you create a new multi value parameter in SSRS which uses the results of the dataset mentioned above as it's input.

Comment: Created another dataset which runs the query to get the parameter values. But not sure how to use the values in Rss.

Comment: What is the goal? To have 1 RSS feed with all the values or an RSS feed for each value? I have never really used the RSS output from SSRS - never found a need for it.

Comment: SSRS report with different parameters and data with each parameter value should be split to different excel file.
For Example : Emp1, Emp2,Emp3 are the parameter values. These 3 should be split in to 3 different files. Output would be Emp1.xls , Emp2.xls and Emp3.xls. How can this be achieved programatically?

Comment: So this really has nothing to do with RSS then, correct? What you are looking for is a data driven subscription (either emailed Excel attachments or files dumped to a shared drive location).

Comment: Data driven Subscription is not available because we are using standard edition. I use rss script to automate the files but I had to add all the parameter values. But not sure if we can pass dynamic values in the same script.

Comment: Got it. Without DDS I am not sure how this would be achieved directly in SSRS. Some other tool or piece of custom code would be required.